# Evil mode and regular expressions

Tags: evil, regular-expressions

In Vim, if I want search for all variable names LX where X is a number, I can simply type `/L\d`. However, this doesn't seem to work with `evil`.

Is there another syntax for regular expressions in Evil mode, or will I have to fall back on some Emacs functionality for search and replace using regular expressions?

I am using `spacemacs`, and I am pretty clueless regarding most things in Emacs, happily staying in Evil mode all day :).

Comment: Where are you trying to search? In a document or in emac's global variables?

Comment: I am searching in a text document

Comment: Are you using `isearch` or something like `helm-swoop` or `swiper`? The last two should be able to do what you want easily. If you want to use the normal `isearch` function but want to use a different regexp engine look at https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp-steroids.el

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`evil` uses the Emacs regexp facilities under the hood.  Unfortunately, Emacs does not appear to have a separate [syntax
class](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html) for digits, and does not recognize the `\d` [regexp](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression) class.

So, to match your variable named `LX` where `X` is a digit, it
looks like you're stuck with the clunky `/L[0-9]` or the even clunkier `/L[[:digit:]]`.

Note that, in principle, it looks like you could use [character
codes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html)
as listed by `describe-categories`:

```
`\cc`

matches any character whose category is *c*.  Here *c* is a
character that represents a category: thus, 'c' for Chinese
characters or 'g' for Greek characters in the standard
category table. You can see the list of all the currently
defined categories with `M-x describe-categories RET`. You can
also define your own categories in addition to the standard
ones using the `define-category` function (see Categories).
```

According to `describe-categories`, digits are category 6.
Hence, `/L\c6` should work (although it doesn't for me, even
though other categories do).  Still, you wouldn't be saving
yourself much awkward typing when compared to `/L[0-9]`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Think I can live with the clunky syntax for now. Just happy to search replace in a more conveniently way again, and I just tested that it even works with capture patterns, yay!